# Update column with last update of row in Google Sheets... except the header

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I've been using this code to find the most recent update of a given row:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();  
if( r.getColumn() != 5 ) { //checks the column
var row = r.getRow();
var time = new Date();
time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-07:00", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E" + row.toString()).setValue(time);
};
};
```

The problem is that I'd like to have a header on column 'E' and I need to make sure that the script doesn't overwrite the header if someone changes something in that header row. I've tried using "E2:E" or "E2:1000" as a replacement in getRange but the effect is that when any row is updated, ALL of column E gets updated with the timestamp.

Question is: how do exclude Row 1 from being overwritten by this script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer

Replace `if( r.getColumn() != 5 )` by `if( r.getColumn() != 5 && r.getRow() != 1 )` .

## Long answer

`&&` is the AND operator `r.getRow() != 1` compares the row of the edited cell with the row number that you want to be skipped.

### Full code minimal modification

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();  
  if( r.getColumn() != 5 && r.getRow() != 1) { //checks the column & row
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-07:00", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E" + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
};
```

### Full code improved

Taking advantage that onEdit() event gets an event object that include the range.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var r = e.range;
  var s = r.getSheet();  
  if( r.getColumn() != 5 && r.getRow() != 1) { //checks the column & row
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-07:00", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    s.getRange("E" + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
};
```

## References

- [Logical Operators - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)
- [JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operators - w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)